# Unable to submit multiple guest objects using createObjects API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Fail to create guest objects by using createObjects API method. refer the below sample code,

```
    Image image = new Image();
    image.setCapacity(50L);

    Guest guest = new Guest();
    guest.setHostname("malya-vm-4");
    guest.setDomain("test.com");
    guest.setStartCpus(1l);
    guest.setMaxMemory(1024l);
    guest.setDatacenter(new Location());
    guest.getDatacenter().setName("che01");

    guest.setLocalDiskFlag(false);
    guest.setHourlyBillingFlag(true);

    guest.setOperatingSystemReferenceCode("UBUNTU_LATEST");

    Component privateComponent = new Component();
    Component publicComponent = new Component();

    Vlan networkVlan1 = new Vlan();
    networkVlan1.setVlanNumber(1365L);
    networkVlan1.setId(2117919L);

    Subnet privateSubnet = new Subnet();
    privateSubnet.setId(1059121L);

    privateComponent.setNetworkVlan(networkVlan1);
    privateComponent.setPrimarySubnet(privateSubnet);
    guest.setPrimaryBackendNetworkComponent(privateComponent);

    Vlan networkVlan2 = new Vlan();
    networkVlan2.setId(2117917L);
    networkVlan2.setVlanNumber(1290L);

    Subnet primarySubnetVersion4 = new Subnet();
    primarySubnetVersion4.setVersion(4L);
    primarySubnetVersion4.setId(1547547L);

    Subnet ipv6 = Subnet.service(client, 1512739L).getObject();
    Subnet primarySubnetVersion6 = new Subnet();
    primarySubnetVersion6.setVersion(6L);
    primarySubnetVersion6.setId(1512739L);
    primarySubnetVersion6.setSubnetType("PRIMARY_6");

     networkVlan2.setPrimarySubnet(primarySubnetVersion4);
    networkVlan2.setPrimarySubnetVersion6(ipv6);
    networkVlan2.setPrimarySubnetCount(2L);

    publicComponent.setNetworkVlan(networkVlan2);
    guest.setPrimaryNetworkComponent(publicComponent);

    List<Guest> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(guest);
    Guest.service(client).createObjects(list);
```

I am getting the below error message while submit the above request,

> Exception in thread "main" com.softlayer.api.ApiException$Internal: The property 'hostname' must be set to create an instance of 'SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'.(code: SoftLayer_Exception_MissingCreationProperty, status: 500)
>       at com.softlayer.api.ApiException.fromError(ApiException.java:16)
>       at com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient$ServiceProxy.logAndHandleResponse(RestApiClient.java:258)
>       at com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient$ServiceProxy.invokeService(RestApiClient.java:300)
>       at com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient$ServiceProxy.invoke(RestApiClient.java:466)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.createObjects(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue with the Softlayer's Java client, you need to report it here https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java/issues , what I can see in the logs is that the client is not calling the method "createObjects" in the requests there is not any method request when the API sees this it tries to call the createObject method by default:

```
Running POST on https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest.json with body: {"parameters":[[{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest","maxMemory":1024,"hostname":"rcaberodeleteme","domain":"test.com","hourlyBillingFlag":true,"startCpus":1,"operatingSystemReferenceCode":"UBUNTU_LATEST","localDiskFlag":false,"datacenter":{"complexType":"SoftLayer_Location","name":"che01"}}]]}
Got 500 on https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest.json with body: {"error":"The property 'hostname' must be set to create an instance of 'SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_MissingCreationProperty"}
```